# Perl Crons Jobs = High Server Load?

Tags: linux, perl, centos, cpanel

I have multiple cron jobs written in Perl and they appear to be causing a high server load.

When I run `top` through SSH it shows that Perl is using the most CPU and memory.  However, since there's multiple cron jobs, I need to know specifically which one is using the most resources.

Is there any way to check which of the Perl files is using the most resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the PID of the process top shows is using cpu. Then do a

```
ps -ef | grep perl
```

Match the PID to one listed and you'll see the full commandline of the perl process for the high cpu job.

Comment: You can also see the full command-line in top by pressing 'c', although this will require a wide terminal window.  Also if you have the PID, you can do `ps -fp $pid`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you look at `ps -ef` you should see which script maps to that process id. You could also use `strace -fTt -p <pid>` to attach a debugger to a specific process id to see what it's doing.

Or you could modify the script to change `$0` to something meaningful that tells you which script is which.

But it's hard to say without a bit more detail. Is there any chance the script is taking longer to run than you cron job takes to 'fire'? Because if you start backlogging a cron job you'll slowly get worse as more and more start piling up behind it.